# Oracle Amazon RDS No suitable Driver

Tags: oracle, jdbc, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to Oracle 11 Amazon RDS database.  I can connect fine from SQL Developer but when I try from an ant script I get

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable Driver for dev.cob.useast1.rds.amazonaws.com:8120
:dev
```

I am using ojdbc6.jar.

The same script works fine when connecting to my local Oracle Database.

Comment: Might be helpful to show the relevant part of the ant script (with credentials obscured, of course), as there isn't much to go on here. It doesn't look like an Amazon RDS issue particularly, since ant doesn't know how to start talking to it. Can you connect to any remote DB, or even your local one using a remote-type connect string?

Comment: These are the paramters                   database.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
database.jdbc.jar=ojdbc6.jar
database.username=ANDREW
database.password=ANDREW
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@dev.cob.useast1.rds.amazonaws.com:8120:amxbpm
database.sid=amxbpm
This is the ant script part in question
<target name="alter" description="Alter tables">
<sql driver="${database.driver}" 
url="${database.url}" 
userid="${database.username}" 
password="${database.password}" 
delimiter="/" 
keepformat="true">
<classpath>
<pathelement location="${basedir}/${database.jdbc.jar}"/>
</classpath>
<path>

Comment: The same script works fine when connecting to a local Oracle database.

Comment: Can you add that to the question so it can be formatted please, not as a comment; and include the local connection version too for comparison? Also, does `dev.cob.useast1.rds.amazonaws.com` resolve for you?

Comment: Issue was incorrect format URL supplied by the vendor. I typed in my version of their URL above and realized then it didn't match their given one. Asked them to confirm the change and now works.

Theirs said oracle:thin::@dev.cob.useast1.rds.amazonaws.com:8120:amxbpm

Thanks